# Materialize CSS on ASP.NET, MVC, and Angularjs: Collapsible objects won't open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, materialize

I'm using ASP.NET with MVC framework and on top of that Angularjs to handle the client side.

I'm trying to achieve mobile webpage with material design feel and I went for the Materialize.

When I try to create unsorted list (where objects are collapsible) with angular foreach loop, the objects won't collapse.

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="expandable" ng-repeat="item in items" >
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">{{item.name}}</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>TEST</p></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The loop works and creates list of objects with the right names on them, but when clicked, nothing happens.